# Archive submission to App Store failed in Xcode 7.0 for Test Flight

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect, code-signing, testflight, xcode7-beta2

I am submitting a prerelease app to the App Store for internal testing with Test Flight in Xcode 7.0 beta 2 (7A121l). I was able to submit the archive with zero problems multiple times but today I am seeing the following error message. Xcode version or project settings did not change.

> ERROR ITMS-90035: "Invalid Signature. Code object is not signed at all. Make sure you have signed your application with a distribution certificate, not an ad hoc certificate or a development certificate.

[image]

I am using "iOS Developer" code signing identity for Release. My code signing settings at target level are the following:

[image]

According to [this blog post](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-8-beta-testing-with-testflight--cms-22224) one needs to use 'iOS Developer' code signing identity for Test Flight release builds. Is it correct?

#### Signing release with iOS Distribution

I have tried changing the Release settings to `iOS Distribution` but I am still getting the same error.

[image]

### Update

I managed to fix the problem and now it uploads to the App Store. I had an external Framework which I built with Carthage. All I needed to do is to open this framework project and remove `Framework search path` setting from it. Then I rebuilt the framework with carthage and uploaded the app to the App Store.

Comment: Have you tried a clean (command-K) and a force clean (command-option-K) and resubmitting?

Comment: Yes, I did clean and removed the build directory. Did not help.

Comment: @Evgenii I am having the same issue. But when I remove the `Framework search path`  setting then my external Framework can't find any of its own external frameworks that are also imported with carthage. Did your external framework have any dependencies on other 3rd Party frameworks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scheme of the app should be "Release" and not Debug or Ad-Hoc. You can change it by going to Product -> Scheme -> Edit scheme